# Show that if $*$ is a binary operation on the set $S$ which has an identity, then the identity is unique.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is how I went about the problem, but I'm wanting a second opinion.

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the identity is not unique. Let $a,b\in S$ such that $a$ and $b$ are identities in $*$. Then $a*b=a$ and $a*b=b$ so

$a=a*b=b \implies a=b$

but $a\neq b$ because the identity is not unique.

Therefore, the identity must be unique.

Comment: Just to be sure: is the identity two-sided? Also, use your argument without the contradiction :) it saves you one line of writing.

Comment: The question does not say whether it is or isn't. Should I do it both ways to be safe?

Comment: The problem is that if it is only a one-sided identity, your technique doesn't work (and I don't think the statement would be true, but I can't think of a counterexample off-hand).

Comment: I assume the OP has been given the definition of an identity as being a *two-sided* identity, as otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: If your definition of identity is as an element $e$ such that for all elements $a$ we have $a*e=a=e*a,$ then you're dealing with two-sided identities. A left-identity is an element $e$ such that for all elements $a$ we have $e*a=a.$ A right-identity is an element $e$ such that for all elements $a$ we have $a*e=a$. Also, I recommend that you take @Clayton's advice. If you ever manage to prove what you're trying to prove while searching for a contradiction, then you're probably better off proceeding directly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of 2 by 2 matrices with bottom row entries $0$, so
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b  \\
0 & 0 
\end{array}\right),
$$
with ordinary matrix multiplication. 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 
\end{array}\right)
$$
is a left identity.

But so is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 37  \\
0 & 0 
\end{array}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just say $1 = 11' = 1'$.  Then you're done.